# Why it gives an error says "error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer"?

Tags: c, operating-system

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int total_frames, total_pages, hit = 0;
    int pages[25], frame[10], arr[25], time[25];
    int m, n, page, flag, k, minimum_time, temp;
    printf("Enter Total Number of Pages:\t");
    scanf("%d", &total_pages); 
    printf("Enter Total Number of Frames:\t");
    scanf("%d", &total_frames);
/*LFU algrithm */
    for(m = 0; m < total_frames; m++)
    {
        frame[m] = -1;
    }
    for(m = 0; m < 25; m++)
    {
        arr[m] = 0;
    }
    printf("Enter Values of Reference String\n");
    for(m = 0; m < total_pages; m++)
    {
        printf("Enter Value No.[%d]:\t", m + 1);
        scanf("%d", &pages[m]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(m = 0; m < total_pages; m++)
    {
            arr[pages[m]]++;
            time[pages[m]] = m;
            flag = 1;
            k = frame[0];
            for(n = 0; n < total_frames; n++)
            {
                if(frame[n] == -1 || frame[n] == pages[m])
                {
                    if(frame[n] != -1)
                    {
                            hit++;
                    }
                    flag = 0;
                    frame[n] = pages[m];
                    break;
                }
                if(arr[k] > arr[frame[n]])
                {
                    k = frame[n];
                }
            }
            if(flag)
            {
                minimum_time = 25;
                for(n = 0; n < total_frames; n++)
                {
                if(arr[frame[n]] == arr[k] && time[frame[n]] <minimum_time)
                    {
                        temp = n;
                        minimum_time = time[frame[n]];
                    }
                }
                arr[frame[temp]] = 0;
                frame[temp] = pages[m];
            }
            for(n = 0; n < total_frames; n++)
        {
                printf("%d\t", frame[n]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Page Hit:\t%d\n", hit);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: The output]

***In LFU Page Replacement method, the page with the minimum count is selected for replacement with the page that needs to enter into the system. LFU is a cache algorithm which is used to manage computer’s memory. A counter is assigned to every block of memory that is loaded into the cache memory***

Comment: The write way to put a comment is `/*LFU algrithm */` or is it the problem with your formatting here? ;)

Comment: it the problem with your formatting

Comment: Kindly include just enough lines of code to reproduce the problem. Currently it is too long, didn't mind reading

Comment: {
                    minimum_time = 25;
                    for(n = 0; n < total_frames; n++)
                    {
                    if(arr[frame[n]] == arr[k] && time[frame[n]] <minimum_time)
                        {
                            temp = n;
                            minimum_time = time[frame[n]];
                        }
                    }     /* The error is in if condtion */

Comment: `time` is the name of a function in the `<time.h>` header. This may not work, but try changing the time variable's name to, say `time_arr`.

Comment: I change it but  I still get the same error.

Comment: It would be nice if you got a more modern version of GCC which reported the text of the line that has the error (GCC 5 or later).  Copy'n'pasting your code puts line 59 somewhat after the `if` condition you identify.  When I compile your code with my fussy options, I don't get the error you get — which suggests that the code you show isn't the code you're compiling.  I get told that `page` is unused (delete it) and the `temp` may be used without being initialized (initialize it).  But I do not get the 'subscripted value' complaint.

Comment: I  running C Program using Virtual Machine. Which 'n' should I copy?

Comment: PLEASE put relevant information into your question instead of replying in comments. Your question is incomplete without it. Also, avoid screenshots. Paste in and format the relevant text as code.